# Authenticated AJAX request to php service (for Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, authentication

I got a simple website which uses d3.js to plot graphs. The data used for plotting is AJAX requested from a php service per GET with some parameters. The php service then answers with a JSON containing the data.

Now I need to secure that website so only logged in users can access it. My first solution was to use a WordPress with the "restrict user access" plugin. That works so far for the access to the page displaying the d3.js graph, but as I had to learn doesn't hinder the access to my php service.

My question is now, which would be the best and easiest way to implement an authentication for the php service so that it only answers to logged in users.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Read this http://zinoui.com/blog/ajax-basic-authentication

Comment: Enqueue javascript file when a user is logged in. Or check if a user logged in then call ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an article that works in my case:

http://dovy.io/wordpress/authenticating-outside-of-wordpress-on-diff-domain/

My php service now checks via cookie whether the user is logged in to wordpress or not. (as described at this link)